# How to switch from Zen-Cart to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

My website when you type the domain sends you to the current Zen-Cart shopping cart.  I have populated my Magento cart with my products and I'm now ready to make my new Magento shopping cart the main cart when people go to the website.  Right now the Magento is a folder off the public folder that you have to type in the /magento/ after the domain for example, "www.MY_DOMAIN.com/magento/".  I want to now have the Magento cart show up when customers type just our website for example, "www.MY_DOMAIN.com".  I know that I can just do a URL permanent forward but I would like it so when you see the address box it no longer has the forward slash magento.

www.MY_DOMAIN.com (this is current a Zen-Cart shopping cart)
www.MY_DOMAIN.com/magento/ (this is where my Magento shopping cart is)

Comment: Well, you should move zencart to a folder as a backup. Then move Magento to the root of the public folder and change your base url to be the www.MY_DOMAIN.com. Be careful with hidden files such as .htaccess

Comment: Thanks do you have a list of all the folders that I would need to move.  Looking for a step by step.